# Using ORM for a multi-lingual site

Tags: php, orm, localization

I would like to ask for recommendations using ORM (over MySQL) and PHP. Until today I was a CodeIgniter user but now I want to code with FUEL (http://fuelphp.com) and they have a ORM.

My problem is that 75% of the sites I've to code have 2 or more language and the data is repeated (title for lang1, 2, 3... description for lang1, 2, 3...). Actually I'm doing this with CodeIgniter:

```
$data = $this->db->where('id', $id)->get('pages')->row();

if(false == $data)
    return false;

$this->db->where('module', 'pages')->where('pk', $data->id)->where("locale", $locale);

$query = $this->db->get("translations");

foreach($query->result() as $row)
    $result->{$row->label} = $row->value;

$result->_data = $data;
```

Using a MySQL structure:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `id_user` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `id_parent` INT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `order` INT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `template` INT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
  `image` VARCHAR(125) NULL ,
  `flag_active` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
  `flag_shop` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `modified` INT NULL ,
  `created` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `translations` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `id_user` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `locale` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `module` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `pk` INT NOT NULL ,
  `label` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `value` TEXT NULL ,
  `modified` INT NULL ,
  `created` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I think it is self descriptive but first I add a page and then, for each page, I add a translations entry with module=table_name, locale=language, pk=id_page, label=title/description/..., value=value.

I would like to evolve this and see how I can handle in a better way using ORM, what is the best way for rapid-development, etc.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set this up using our Orm you'd first need to create the models. When using MySQL you don't absolutely need to configure the properties but I'll do it anyway because it save a query per model to find them out.

#### Model_Page

```
class Model_Page extends Orm\Model {

    protected static $_properties = array(
        'id',
        'id_user',
        'id_parent' => array('default' => 0),
        'order' => array('default' => 0),
        'template' => array('default' => 1),
        'image',
        'flag_active' => array('default' => 1),
        'flag_shop' => array('default' => 0),
        'modified',
        'created'
    );

    protected static $_has_many = array(
        'translations' => array(
            'key_to' => 'pk',
        ),
    );

    protected static $_belongs_to = array(
        'parent' => array(
            'model_to' => 'Model_Page',
            'key_from' => 'id_parent',
        ),
    )
}
```

#### Model_Translation

```
class Model_Page extends Orm\Model {

    protected static $_properties = array(
        'id',
        'id_user',
        'locale',
        'module',
        'pk',
        'label',
        'value',
        'modified',
        'created'
    );

    protected static $_belongs_to = array(
        'page' => array(
            'key_from' => 'pk',
        ),
    )
}
```

And your query becomes this:

```
$page = Model_Page::query()
    ->related('translations')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->where('translations.module', 'pages')
    ->where('translations.locale', $locale)
    ->get();

if (empty($page))
{
    return false;
}

$result = array();
foreach ($page->translations as $t)
{
    $result[$t->label] = $t->value;
}
$result['_data'] = $page;
```

[Check the docs](http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/intro.html) for more explantion and examples.

Comment: Hello Jelmer: thank you in advance! Various questions: 1) the second model has to be named *Model_Translation*, no? 2) The $_belongs_to of the first model, has to point model_to=>"Model_Translation"? Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1) You can name it whatever you want, but you'll need to configure more if you do.
2) Not necessary when it's called "Model_Translation" because the relation name "relations" will be converted to "Model_Translation" for the expected model when not configured. This is explained in the docs.

Comment: Thank you, I've to try it and see it. :)!